# Page name appears on the browser tab for a second before the actual page title appears

Tags: html, css, browser

I am really unsure what is causing this or whether it is only local to my computer (since I am running the website off by computer -- still in development).

Upon navigation to another webpage, the webpages html file name appears on the browser tab for a second before the title appears. Eg: "contact.html" will appear for a second and will change to my Title which is "Contact"

Any one have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: That's how they do it ... showing the file name until they loaded the DOM and gets the title tag

Comment: @LGSon Any reason why this is happening to my site? Will this not happen when I put it onto a server and take it live? For example when visiting stack overflows website I dont see this happening. I see stackoverflow.com and Then the title.

Comment: This is normal behavior and happens to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normal. and you should not worry about it. but a few points might help :

put title tag on almost top of other tags inside of head

```
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  ...
</head>
```

and check your browser network throttling speed. it might be changed already due to developing issues. set it to "No throttling". { on google chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+I and go to Network tab, it's there. }

how do you open your files? are they on local server or not? if not, install a local server like xampp for php or iis for asp. in browser the url should be something like http://localhost/mysite/myfile.html
or http://127.0.0.1/mysite/myfile.html

these methods should solve your problem.